# Sublime Text 3 JSX Linting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sublimetext3, eslint, jsx

My ESLint setup is giving me the following error in my React-Native app:

[image]

```
Mixed spaces and tabs: Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 14.
```

For some reason it wants the lines that it doesn't like to only be indented 4 spaces instead of 14 which it should be.

Here is what the linter accepts:

[image]

Obviously lines 25-27 is not what I want.

Is there some setting I am missing or an additional plugin that will accomplish this?

I am using:

- ESLint
- Sublime Text 3
- Sublime Babel plugin for JSX highlighting
- The following .eslintrc
- The following eslint plugins/dependencies

.eslintrc

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb/base", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "react-native"
    ],
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "jasmine": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 2],
        "no-console": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": [1, {"vars": "local", "args": "none"}],
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 1,
        "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
        "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 1,
        "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
        "react/jsx-indent-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-key": 1,
        "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
        "react/jsx-quotes": 0,
        "jsx-quotes": 1,
        "react/sort-prop-types": 1,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/no-danger": 1,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
        "react/no-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
        "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
        "react/prop-types": 1,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
        "react/require-extension": 1,
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/sort-comp": 1,
        "react/wrap-multilines": 1,
        "id-length": 0,
        "react-native/no-unused-styles": 2,
        "react-native/split-platform-components": 2
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pluralReact",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "template",
  "author": "= <=> (=)",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main.js",
  "exp": {
    "sdkVersion": "5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.5",
    "react-native": "github:exponentjs/react-native#sdk-5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

ANSWER:

Changing the surrounding Image tag by using spaces instead of table solved the issue:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using spaces to indent, not tabs? You might want to add this setting to your user preferences: `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`

Comment: I added that the use preferences but it didn't help because the issue is that it only wants 4 spaces and not more. See my edit for what the linter thinks is correct.

Comment: With the given setting enabled, you would still have to reindent. Your screenshot makes it difficult to tell whether you currently use tabs or spaces, the setting `"draw_white_space": "all"` helps to visually distinct the two.

Comment: Good catch. See my edits and the edit to the error message I am now getting

Comment: Does it change when you use the same type of indentation before `<Image`?

Comment: Also, I did set "tab_size": 2 so I could use tab

Comment: That fixed it...but idk why because if I set "tab_size": 2, should that function as if I had typed 2 spaces. I think there might be a "tabs to spaces" setting I can set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is likely indented by tabs not spaces. There's a setting that makes the visual distinction easier.

```
"draw_white_space": "all"
```

(By default it's set to `"selection"`, so you will only see those visual cues when selecting your code)

Since the JSX linter (among others) seems to prefer spaces over tabs, you should use add the following to your user settings.

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
"tab_size": 2
```

Make sure to re-indent your code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use **eslint-config-airbnb-standard** npm module:

```
npm install -g eslint-config-airbnb-standard
```

It installs `eslint` globally. It uses Airbnb style config + StandardJS config. Easy to install, works with Sublime Text 3 and WebStorm. Check [installation instructions here](https://github.com/doasync/eslint-config-airbnb-standard).

[image]